# Button in highlighted state till API call finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a button in my react application, on click of that button I make an API call, and wait for this API call to finish before updating the redux store.

My button looks highlighted until the API call finishes and it gives an impression that UI is freezed.

```
// Button Class

onButtonClick(action) {
   this.props.executeAction();
}

// Action creator
export function executeAction() {
   return (dispatch) => {
           serverCall().catch((err) => console.log(err))
   }
}

serverCall = () => {
  const req = request.post(`${DATA_URL}`);
  return req.endAsync();
}
```

How can I ensure that button is not highlighted for that long.

[image]

Button in normal state

[image]

Button in highlighted state

Leads here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does your button stay like that in the first place? Are you using special CSS or a styling framework? The script you posted is largely if not completely unrelated to this issue, as far as I can tell. There's nothing intrinsic about React or AJAX that would make a button stay active or whatever is causing this.

Comment: It will be because executeAction is a sync call and until it finishes, onButtonClick is not done.

Comment: Are you saying the call freezes your page? Why not use an async call then?

Comment: Don't make sync calls as that does freeze the UI not just give the appearance of it being frozen. Use async and success/fail/completion events on the call.